# Running multiple python scripts sequentially with nohup

Tags: bash, shell

```sh
requests=(25 50 75 100)
factors=(3 6)
graphsizes=(25 50 75)

for request in "${requests[@]}" 
do
  for factor in "${factors[@]}"
  do
    for size in "${graphsizes[@]}"
    do
        echo "Now Running: n = ${request}, factor = ${factor}, size = ${size}" >> nohup.out
        nohup python3 -u main.py "$request" 50 "$factor" "$size" > ${request}_${factor}_${size}.log 
        echo "Done Running: n = ${request}, factor = ${factor}, size = ${size}" >> nohup.out
    done
  done
done
```

My intention: I want to run all the various permutation of arguments to `main.py` sequentially; i.e., print `Now Running...`, then call `nohup` and run the python script, when that is done print `Done running...`

Note that I cannot add a `&` at the end of the `nohup` line, since that would make the script proceed before `main.py` has finished.

However, by not using the `&`, I can no longer use the current shell process while this script is running. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the use of `nohup` is if you're not putting the process in the background.

Comment: You could open a new terminal while this script is running, that's easiests.

Comment: @9769953 I need the process to continue running after I close the terminal (it is a server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want, is the following: remove the `nohup` from the commands in your shell script, but run the overarching script that you show here (i.e., all the code; let's call it `iterations.bash` with `nohup` and in the background: `nohup bash iterations.bash >& iterations.log &`. Now you have your command line back, while the processes *inside* the script are run sequentially.